# How to call two methods on button's onclick method in HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How to call two methods on button's onclick method in HTML or JavaScript ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. Try this:

   ```
   <input type="button" onclick="function1();function2();" value="Call2Functions" />
   ```
2. Or, call second function at the end of first function:

   ```
      function func1(){
        //--- some logic
        func2();
      }

      function func2(){
       //--- some logic
      }
   ```

   ...and call func1() onclick of button:

   ```
   <input type="button" onclick="func1();" value="Call2Functions" />
   ```

Answer (score 20):

As stated by Harry Joy, you can do it on the `onclick` attr like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="func1();func2();" value="Call2Functions" />
```

Or, in your JS like so:

```
document.getElementById( 'Call2Functions' ).onclick = function()
{
    func1();
    func2();
};
```

Or, if you are assigning an onclick programmatically, and aren't sure if a previous onclick existed (and don't want to overwrite it):

```
var Call2FunctionsEle = document.getElementById( 'Call2Functions' ),
    func1 = Call2FunctionsEle.onclick;

Call2FunctionsEle.onclick = function()
{
    if( typeof func1 === 'function' )
    {
        func1();
    }
    func2();
};
```

If you need the functions run in scope of the element which was clicked, a simple use of apply could be made:

```
document.getElementById( 'Call2Functions' ).onclick = function()
{
    func1.apply( this, arguments );
    func2.apply( this, arguments );
};
```

Answer (score 10):

**The modern event handling method:**

```
element.addEventListener('click', startDragDrop, false);
element.addEventListener('click', spyOnUser, false);
```

The first argument is the event, the second is the function and the third specifies whether to allow event bubbling.

From [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html):

> W3C’s DOM Level 2 Event specification pays careful attention to the problems of the traditional model. It offers a simple way to register as many event handlers as you like for the same event on one element.
>
> The key to the W3C event registration model is the method `addEventListener()`. You give it three arguments: the event type, the function to be executed and a boolean (true or false) that I’ll explain later on. To register our well known doSomething() function to the onclick of an element you do:

Full details here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

**Using jQuery**

if you're using jQuery, there is a nice API for event handling:

```
$('#myElement').bind('click', function() { doStuff(); });
$('#myElement').bind('click', function() { doMoreStuff(); });
$('#myElement').bind('click', doEvenMoreStuff);
```

Full details here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: I can never remember in this model, is the code you showed fully cross browser compatible, or are there concerns to consider in that regard? **EDIT:** based on your edit, I'll add that I can never remember the addEventListener model, and implications thereof, because I always use jQuery.

Comment: There are caveats of course when you look at older browsers, but if you use jQuery to handle it, you're pretty safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" onclick="functionA();functionB();" />

function functionA()
{

}

function functionB()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi,**

You can also do as like below... In this way, your both functions should call and if both functions return true then it will return true else return false.

```
<input type="button" 
     onclick="var valFunc1 = func1(); var valFunc2 = func2(); if(valFunc1 == true && valFunc2 ==true) {return true;} else{return false;}" 
     value="Call2Functions" />
```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**