# How to get one button to do two functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

At the moment i have two buttons one that changes the text to red (default) and the other when clicked changes it to green. Instead of having two buttons I need one button to say green when the text appears red so when you click on the green button it changes the colour to green and then the same button says red now and when clicked it'll change the text to red

THIS IS MY SCRIPT:

```
function change1() { 
 txt = document.getElementById("txt");
 txt.style.color = 'green';
}

    function change2() { 
    txt = document.getElementById("txt");
    txt.style.color = 'red';
}
```

And these are my buttons

```
<input type="button" value="Green" onclick="change1()" id="btn">

<input type="button" value="Red" onclick="change2()" id="btn">
```

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882313/how-to-call-two-methods-on-buttons-onclick-method-in-html-or-javascript

Comment: What element(s) are being changed? What is `txt`?

Comment: If all you're doing is toggling something, you only ever need one function (and an `if` statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it easy with an if statement asking for `style.color` property:

```
function change() { 
  txt = document.getElementById("txt");
  if (txt.style.color === 'green'){
        txt.style.color = 'red';
  }
  else {
    txt.style.color = 'green';
  }
}
```

Is not a good practice attach your **JavaScript** in the HTML element, instead that you can retrieve the button by code and then use the `addEventListener` method to attach the `change` function to the `click` event, check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/QwbNQg) to see how it works.

Comment: thank you thats working for me really appreciate it would i do an if statement again to change the name in the button from red to green also

Comment: @Valerie Great, check out the codepen, I have updated it to fit your requirement. (http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/QwbNQg)

Answer (score 0):

### Script Adjustment

The easiest method is to use the current value of the button to determine which action to take:

```
function colorChange(button1) {
    var txt = document.getElementById("txt");

    if (button1.value == "Green") {
        txt.style.color = 'green';
        button1.value == "Red";
    } else {
        txt.style.color = 'red';
        button1.value == "Green";
    }
}
```

### Alternate

You may instead use a global variable to track the state of the button, but this is a less desirable solution:

```
var txt;
var colorButtonIsGreen = true;

function colorChange() {
    if(!txt) txt = document.getElementById("txt");

    if (colorButtonIsGreen) {
        txt.style.color = 'green';
        button1.value == "Red";
    } else {
        txt.style.color = 'red';
        button1.value == "Green";
    }

    colorButtonIsGreen != colorButtonIsGreen;
}
```

### HTML:

Slightly adjusted original HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Green" onclick="colorChange(this);" id="btn">
```