# How to call two functions is an html input type?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

This is my code :

```
<input maxlength="10" type="text" onclick="check()" onkeypress="check()" onkeypress="check()" required="true" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" name="contact" placeholder="Ex: 9923548879">
```

I want to implement, 2 function in the onclick event like..

```
onclick="check()" & onclick="get()"
```

How to do? so because, if the do so, 1 function get overridden by another

Comment: in the case of click call `get()` inside the function `check()`

Comment: Why you are not call second function inside in first function? This 2 function have same functionality then use one function.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="check(); get();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function check(){
  // your code

  get()// call your second function

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want, you just write near the first function as describe in below links.

[How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event)

[Call two functions from same onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025138/call-two-functions-from-same-onclick)

```
onClick="doSomething();doSomethingElse();"
```

Also check this link :- [How to call two methods on button's onclick method in HTML or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882313/how-to-call-two-methods-on-buttons-onclick-method-in-html-or-javascript)